# how to calculate total number of L Prasent in my table with in 1 year for a person

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to make a web app for salary management. In which I want to calculate total number of leaves with in a year if there is more than 16 L present in my table than it will count as A absent.

How to make procedure for this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could work.

```
SELECT
     EmployeeID,
     DaysAbsent=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT aDate)FROM aDateTable
                  WHERE Absent=1 and EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID)
FROM 
    Employess
```